# How to Simulate Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

I want to gain practice simulating multiple inheritance with the use of interfaces in C#. However, I do not fully understand. Can someone explain to me where my thinking is wrong?

I have two classes inverter and sequence. Inverter has a .doAction() that just swaps character placements within a string. Sequence is actually a class hierarchy of one parent and two children. They just manipulate a string by a .doAction() method in various ways. THe objects in sequence are all differentiated by overriding the .doAction() method.

Now, I want to create a new class called invSeq which has the functionality of both inverter and sequence.

What I did is this:

```
public class inVSeq : inverter, seq1, seq2, seq3
```

The interfaces are of the three different .doAction() from each of the classes under the sequence hierarchy.

So from what I understand, is that I must create these seq1, seq2, seq3 (.doAction()) methods again. But how do I reuse the .doAction() methods from the existing sequence hierachy? I do not feel like there is a true linkage between the classes if I just rewrite the code for the interfaces.

I could go with composition (holding private sequence objects (3) within the inVSeq), but that defeats the use of interfaces.

Comment: multiple inheritance is not good, gen-spec relations are so rigid and may cause serious problems later when you want to change your inheritance hierarchy, Favor composition over gen-spec relations. what if `inverter` and `sequence` both have `Foo()`?

Comment: add a gen-spec relation just for code reuse is an anti-pattern and may results in diamond problem soon or later

Comment: Which `doAction` should be called using this code: `inVSeq.doAction()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you just described is called [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and composition of interfaces is integral part of this pattern.

The interface with `doAction()` would be the base component, the various implementations of this interface would be the leaves and the composite would compose those implementations. In this way, the client that calls the `doAction()` doesn't need to know what concrete implementation it is calling, making the code much more modular.

Comment: This helped me think much more clearly. Composition is indeed needed to achieve code reuse-ability. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> could go with composition (holding private sequence objects (3) within the inVSeq), but that defeats the use of interfaces.

This doesn't defeat the use of interfaces, you can pass interfaces into the constructor.

Deriving a class from multiple interfaces means that class needs to implement (i.e. rewrite) the code for all those interface methods (or call the baseclass implementation). Favour composition over inheritance.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.